# Implementation of a Java “ArrayList” like data structure in R to allow fast appending of ReferenceClasses objects one-by-one (probably using rJava)

Tags: java, r, data-structures, arraylist, rjava

I need to perform a discrete event simulation involving lots of general linear regression in R and hence a large number of R objects need to be appended into a list or an array one by one. Now everything has been implemented and the simulator runs. However, I realized that the bottleneck of performance of the whole process is in fact at list append(takes about 15min to simulate 6000 events). I notice that when the number of objects in an R list, vector or array gets large, the insertion becomes very slow. I need a reusable list data structure because it’s used again and again in many parts of the simulation code. Here is my implementation of a simple ArrayList written in R:

```
ArrayListX = setRefClass(
  Class = "ArrayListX",
  fields = list(
    ol = "array",
    len = "integer",
    cap = "integer",
    expandNum = "integer"),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function(){
      len <<- 0L
      expandNum <<- 100000L
      #TODO: The preallocation here made the performance worse.
      ol <<- array(dim = expandNum)
      cap <<- expandNum
    },
    expand = function(){
      ol <<- c(ol, array(list(), dim = expandNum))
      cap <<- cap + expandNum
    },
    get = function(i){
      return(ol[i])
    },
    remove = function(i){
      ol[i] <<- NULL
      len <<- len - 1L
    },
    add = function(obj){
      if(cap <= len)
      {
        expand()
      }
      len <<- len + 1L
      ol[len] <<- obj
      return(len)
    },
    size = function(){
      return(len)
    },
    set = function(i, obj){
      ol[i] <<- obj
    },
    insert = function(before, obj){
      if(before < 1 || before > len + 1)
        throw(paste("Subscript out of bound. before = ", before))

      if(len == 0)
      {
        ol[1] <<- obj
      }  else
      {
        head = ol[1:before - 1]
        head[before] = obj
      {
        if(before <= len)
          ol <<- c(head, ol[before:len])
        else
          ol <<- head
      }
      }
      len <<- len + 1L
    }
  )
)
```

Notice that I tried to initialize the list and preallocate a certain number of rows, this did not improve the performance as well, in fact it’s even slower than without preallocating. (this maybe because of the referenceclasses that I’m using. In my experience, preallocation usually improves performance in R when not using referenceclasses)
That’s why I thought about using Java ArrayList as the backend data structure of the list. I experimented with rJava.

```
ArrayListJ = setRefClass(
  Class = "ArrayListJ",
  contains = "ArrayList",
  fields = list(
    jal = "ANY"),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function(){
      jal <<- .jnew("java.util.ArrayList")
    },
    get = function(i){
      rObj = .jcall(jal, returnSig="Ljava/lang/Object;", method = "get", as.integer(i))
      return(rObj)
    },
    remove = function(i){
    },
    add = function(obj){
      jRef = toJava(x = obj, engine = NULL)
      .jcall(obj = jal, returnSig = "Z", method = "add", .jcast(jRef, new.class = "java/lang/Object"))
    },
    size = function(){
      s = .jcall(obj = jal, returnSig = "I", method = "size")
      return (s)
    },
set = function(i, obj){
    #Not implemented yet.
    },
insert = function(before, obj){
    #Not implemented yet.
    }    
    )
  )
```

I’m now struggling with the “get” function because I could not get it to work. It always returns an REXPReference object which I can’t use in R. What I want it to return is in fact the original R object obj that is added to the ArrayListJ. It needs to be the originally referenced object because the inserted R object could have been updated by other logic after its inserted into the ArrayListJ.
Can someone please help me with the ArrayListX or ArrayListJ implementation? It basically needs to be able to append a large number of R referenceclasses objects into a list one by one at constant time (performance should not slow down when the list gets larger). For the ArrayListJ implementation, how can I get back the originally referenced R object using the “get” method? Thanks.

Comment: Repeat after me: They are called "References Classes".

Comment: Really? Aren't they called "ReferenceClasses" ?

Comment: Yes they are, and the letter-digit combo must die. It is NOT the name to use.